# OpenTK - After multiplying with ProjectionMatrix nothing is rendering anymore

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, opentk

From a tutorial that refused to explain it I got the following code. It was a lwjgl tutorial I copied where it worked perfectly fine. I'm not sure if the problem is created by having OpenGl differ from the java openGl, but since it's only math I would be surprised by that:

```
private void createProjectionMatrix(int width, int height)
{
    float aspectRatio = width / height;
    float yScale = (float)((1f / Math.Tan(Maths.degreeToRadian(FOV/2f))) * aspectRatio);
    float xScale = yScale / aspectRatio;
    float frustumLength = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

    projectionMatrix = new Matrix4();
    projectionMatrix.M11 = xScale;
    projectionMatrix.M22 = yScale;
    projectionMatrix.M33 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustumLength);
    projectionMatrix.M34 = -1;
    projectionMatrix.M43 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustumLength);
    projectionMatrix.M44 = 0;   
}
```

This I multiplied with the transformation matrix (which worked). I get the matrix to the shader by doing `uniformLocation_projectionMatrix = GL.GetUniformLocation(programID, "projectionMatrix")` followed by `GL.UniformMatrix4(uniformLocation_projectionMatrix, false, ref projectionMatrix)` this way I got the transformationMatrix in there too, so this shouldn't be the problem.
In the shader I do `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(in_position,  1.0)` (again, without the projectionMatrix everything works fine), and before that `uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;` (as you can confirm I spelled it exactly the same).
I'm not sure what further part of the code you need, so feel free to ask, thank you.
Edit 1: I tried transposing it (by setting the false to true), the resut was the same

Edit 2:
 The matrix created by the code above:
`(1,428148;       0;          0;  0)
 (       0; 2,53893;          0;  0)
 (       0;       0;  -1,002002; -1)
 (       0;       0; -0,2002002;  0)`

The matrix created by Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView():
`(0,8033332;        0;         0;  0)
 (        0; 1,428148;         0;  0)
 (        0;        0; -1,002002; -1)
 (        0;        0; -0,2002002; 0)`
The matrix created by the layout from Draykoon D's answer:
`(-0,00015625;            0;         0;          0)
 (          0; 0,0002777778;         0;          0)
 (          0;            0; -1,002002; -0,2002002)
 (          0;            0;        -1;          0)`

I am now convinced that the problem lies elsewere - all three matricies don't work.

Edit 3 - More code:
This is my vertexShader so far

```
#version 440 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_textureCoordinates;

uniform mat4 translation;
uniform mat4 rotationX;
uniform mat4 rotationY;
uniform mat4 rotationZ;
uniform mat4 scale;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec2 textureCoordinates;

void main(void)
{
    mat4 transformationMatrix = translation * rotationX * rotationY * rotationZ * scale;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(in_position,  1.0);
    textureCoordinates = in_textureCoordinates;
}
```

And this is the render function:

```
public void render(Entity entity, ShaderProgram shader)
    {
        TexturedModel texturedModel = entity.Model;
        RawModel model = texturedModel.Model;
        GL.BindVertexArray(model.VaoID);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(
            entity.Position, entity.RotX, entity.RotY, entity.RotZ, entity.Scale);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texturedModel.Texture.ID);
        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, model.VertexCount, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
    }
```

and the constructor of the Renderer loads the projectionMatrix:

```
public Renderer(int width, int height, ShaderProgram shader)
    {
        createProjectionMatrix(width, height);
        shader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
    }
```

Comment: Many other things may be wrong. Please, provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Over the last week I carfully put this together, I don't think I am good enough to extract anything. The code I provided is the only thing I changed, and before that it worked... I have the feeling the problem has something to do with depth Buffering or some other depth related thing

Comment: how am I even supposed to do that in an opengl program? There is the shader, the shader loader, the renderer, the gameLoop, the math toolbox, and the entity class providing something to render - all of this is vital, isn't it?

Comment: before I spend at least a dozen hours creating the mcve, could you please verify that the perspective projection matrix is set up correctly?

Comment: make m33 and m43 positive, ensure your planes actually encompass your content, verify that the matrix is correctly submitted to the shader.

Comment: Your `aspectRatio` is wrong, because you are dividing an `int` by an `int`. You should cast one of those values to a `float`.

Comment: it tells me the cast is redundant. I added a lot of brackets, yet it still doesn't fix the problem `float aspectRatio = (float)(width) / ((float)(height));` I also tried making m33 and m43 positive (both ideas in every possible combination). I also can't see why the plane shouldn't encompass my two triangles

Comment: You can compare your perspective matrix with the [OpenTK CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView](http://jeske.github.io/opentkr-doxygen/html/struct_open_t_k_1_1_matrix4.html#ae5e37b458cc2c39d9c0effa6acb1f387) If they are the same your problem lives in other place.

Comment: I did, thanks. They are not the same, but both of them don't work. Is my method of loading it correct? I found some sources stating it should be loaded via `GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)` `GL.LoadMatrix(ref projectionMatrix);` - although I'm not sure how the shader would know I did this..  Also I have `GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)` and `GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Lequal)` in the onLoad, as well as `GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)` in the loop - just in case this is important to know

Comment: The right matrix is [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml). You have exchanged `xScale` and `yScale` when operating with `aspectRatio`.

Comment: The other matrix ("transformation" you say) is important. The way you pass and read it in the shaders is important. If you pass vertices in an order or in the opposite is important. A lot of things matter. That's why I ask for a complete example.

Comment: I put more details in the question. What do you mean I exchanged xScale and yScale? Do I have to swap them?

Comment: The right code: `float yScale = (float)(1f / Math.Tan(Maths.degreeToRadian(FOV/2f)));`

Comment: I don't have to multiply it by the aspectRatio? Interesting. Though sadly it still doesn't fix the problem. Is the order in which I'm multiplying the matricies correct?

Comment: This is my last comment. All of your transform matrices seems to position the triangle(s) in the world. I don't see the view transform unless your camera is at (0,0,0) looking towards (0,0,-1). Add a [lookAt matrix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml)

Comment: The vew matrix I was going to implement after this projection works - one step at a time (I found implementing a lot at once makes it unreasonably hard to find the bug/error if one occurs). The last time I made all of this (back than in lwjgl) it worked perfekt, and the order was fine too. Yes, The 'camera' is still at 0,0,0 , and as I said without the projection matrix the triangles are rendered fine, rotate as I please etc etc. The only thing I can't do is move them a lot in the z direction (positive or negative), this is why I need the projectionMatrix. x and y work just fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150430/discussion-between-harlekintiger-and-ripi2).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try an other method of building this projection matrix, you can try this one with th math [explanation](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)

[image]

should not be too hard,

r and l stand for right and left and should be something like -width/2, width2

b and t stand for bottom and right, -height/2, height/2

n and f stand for near and far plane try different values, just check your z belongs to interval, good luck. I am not sure but look on the scheme to see the sign of near and far plane.

Comment: I tried this matrix, and the program still doesn't work. I put the results in the question above. Do you have any ideas where the loading could have gone wrong? Or better so say, what else could be the problem? I still think it has something to do with the depth test or something

Comment: @harlekintiger what is the range of the z coordonate of your vertices ?

Comment: For the matrix I used `NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f` and `FAR_PLANE = 100`. I'm rendering three 'things' (entitys, basically two triangles displaying a texture). One at  `0, 0, 0`, the second at `0, 0, 80` and the third at `0, 0, -80`. My thoughts were: at least one of them should be visible

Comment: it's a bit strange that you have a <0 value in M11 with your NEAR_PLANE being positive

Comment: The vec3's I provided are the transformation offsets for the transformationMatrix. The vertices themself are` -0.5f,  0.5f, 0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 0.5f,  0.5f, 0f` and the indices `0,1,3, 3,1,2`

Comment: `(2*n)/(r-l) = (2 * 0.1f) / (-(width/2.0f) - (width/2.0f)) = 0.2f / (-(1280/2) - (640)) = 0.2f / -1280 = -0.00015625 ` I did the calculation manually, I guess I got it wrong how to calculate r and l ?

Answer (score 0):

**First and foremost**, before doing anything else, check if you call `GL.UseProgram(shaderProgram)` *directly* after creating the program to avoid arrors like trying to load a projection matrix without having GL using the shader.
Thanks for everyone helping, at least I learned something

Comment: If you had provided a complete example perhaps some body could have found that bug instead of focusing so many comments in matrix definition. Please, learn how to make questions.